# Serialization and Android ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, serialization, classnotfoundexception

Hi I am trying to send a custom list of objects from Client to server. I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException`. I am using Android studio emulator for my client and running my Server on Eclipse. I even wrote a test code to check to see if it works in Eclipse and it does. But for some reason does not work on android. I am new to Android.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;    

public class Document implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String id;
String name;
String address;
String[] category;
float lattitude;
float longitude;
String city;
double stars;
double overallRating;
// String attributes[];
Review[] reviews;

public Document(String id, String name, String address, String[] category, float longitude, float lattitude,
        String city, double stars, double overallRating, Review[] review) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.category = category;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.lattitude = lattitude;
    this.city = city;
    this.stars = stars;
    this.overallRating = overallRating;
    this.reviews = review;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Document [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", category="
            + Arrays.toString(category) + ", lattitude=" + lattitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + ", city=" + city
            + ", stars=" + stars + "]";
}

}

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Review implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1595783420656910821L;
    double stars;
    String review;

    public Review(double stars, String review) {
        this.stars = stars;
        this.review = review;
    }

}
```

//Part of the server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

public class CommunicatewithMobileDevice implements Runnable {
Socket conn;
private InvertedIndexA invertedIndex;
private BufferedReader br;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private PrintWriter pw;

public CommunicatewithMobileDevice(Socket sock, InvertedIndexA invertedIndex) {
    conn = sock;
    this.invertedIndex = invertedIndex;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {

    try {

        String ip = br.readLine();

        String input[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
        System.out.println(ip + " " + input[0] + " " + input[1]);
        List<Document> docs = invertedIndex.search(ip, Float.valueOf(input[0]), Float.valueOf(input[1]));
        System.out.println(docs.size());
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.conn.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(docs);


        oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

//A singleton or a server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Singleton implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket conn;
    private static InvertedIndexA invertedIndex = new InvertedIndexA(Helper.loadCategories());
    private boolean isStopped = false;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static InvertedIndexA getInstance() {
        return invertedIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Thread(new Singleton()).start();
    }

    public void acceptsClients() {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                conn = new ServerSocket(1503);
            }
            while (!isStopped()) {
                Socket sock = conn.accept();
                //System.out.println("Conn accepted");
                new Thread(new CommunicatewithMobileDevice(sock, invertedIndex)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        acceptsClients();
    }
}


    //The android client or a part of it



import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;

public class ListOfResults extends AppCompatActivity {

    CommunicateWithServer comm;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String message = "";
    List<Document> docs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_results);
        comm = new CommunicateWithServer();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        message = bundle.getString("message");
        //new Communicate().execute();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1503);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
                pw.println(message);
                double latitude = 0;
                double longitude = 0;
                pw.println(new String(Double.valueOf(latitude) + " " + Double.valueOf(longitude)));
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                docs = (List<Document>) ois.readObject();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                //Log.e("print the val",br.readLine());
                //System.out.println(docs.size());
                Log.e("size", Integer.toString(docs.size()));


            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("yeassass");
            }
        }
    };

    public void populate(String result) {
        Log.e("here", "here");
        DocumentAdapter documentAdapter = new DocumentAdapter(this, docs);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(documentAdapter);
    }
}
```

//This was a test program i wrote to test the server code. Works fine here

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test implements Runnable {

        public Test() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Test test = new Test();
            new Thread(test).start();
        }

        public void run() {
            testOp();
        }

        private void testOp() {
            try {
                Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1503);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
                String location = Helper.getLocation();
                location = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf(") ") + 2);
                String split[] = location.split(",");
                pw.println("Chinese");
                pw.println(new String(split[0] + " " + split[1]));
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                List<Document> docs = (List<Document>) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(docs);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2263)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication.ListOfResults$1.run(ListOfResults.java:57)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Document" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     ... 20 more
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-26 21:10:04.470 6009-6116/com.kpt.krishgodiawala.myapplication W/System.err:         ... 21 more
```

Comment: Yes I am aware I should be using REST but that is not the goal here. I even tried running the client code inside async task but with no luck. The Document class and review class are the same both in the android studio as well as eclipse.

Comment: You are getting *what* `ClassCastException`? Where is it? Where is the stack trace? What was the message? What *classes* were mentioned in the message? There is enough information there for you to answer your own question, and without it nobody else can.

Comment: Hi added it in the end. And its a ClassNotFound exception that I am facing inside my android client when I try to cast List<Documents> = (List<Document>) ois.readObject(); Sorry for not adding it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document
```

So you don't have a class called `Document` deployed at the client. From the fact that the line of client code compiled, you must have a `Document` class in some other package. That isn't the same class, whatever its name. It has to be same class, same package, same `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: Its the same name and its in the same package. The contents of the class are copy pasted from the one at the server. with the same serialVersioUID. Yeah I too am not sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: It isn't. If it was the same it would work. According to the error message there is *no* package, i.e. there was no package declared in the class at the moment it was serialized.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I wasn't aware of it needing the same package while serialization at both ends. Will read javadocs though!!!! Thanks a ton..

Comment: So it wasn't in the same package. So why did you say it was?

Comment: You misunderstood 'same package'?

Answer (score -1):

according to the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document`, it must because the class name changed at compile time. check the [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to exclude `Document` and `Review` class

**UPDATE:**
also [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/introduction.html) document

Comment: Hey I did look at the documents and added the keep annotation and even tried editing the progaurd-rules.pro but too no luck.

Comment: find your apk file, use this tool `http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/` to unpack the bytecodes, to check is `Document` class there.

Comment: What on earth does 'class name changed at compile time' mean?